# how to change a JSON input from file to URL

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to figure out a way to change the coding from reading a file to a URL. This is the start of the code but everything I've tried ends with syntax errors. Any advice?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    readJson("jsonfilejson.txt");
}

public static void readJson(String file) { 

    Airline airLine = null;
    ArrayList<Airline> list = new ArrayList<Airline>();
    try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line = "";
            String data = "";
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                data += line;
            }
            ArrayList<String> flightsList = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject values = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject nameObject = values.getJSONObject("firstAirline");
                String name = nameObject.get("name").toString();
                JSONArray segmentArray = values.getJSONArray("segments");
                for (int j = 0; j < segmentArray.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject segments = segmentArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    flightsList.add(segments.getString("flightNumber"));
                }
                String stops = values.get("stops").toString();
                JSONObject priceObject = values.getJSONObject("price");
                double price = Double.parseDouble(priceObject.get("amount").toString());

                airLine = new Airline(name, price, flightsList, Integer.parseInt(stops));
                list.add(airLine);
                flightsList.clear();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right track. try converting your string to a url you can read the stream from it

```
 URL fileUrl = new URL(file);


    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileUrl.openStream()));
```

Hope it helps